How to create custom undo/redo buttons for GrapesJS template editor?
I'm working on a project using GrapesJS template editor, and I'm trying to implement undo/redo functionality with two buttons. Of course, the buttons I created do not have currently the undo and redo actions.
Please help me!
<div class="action">
    <a class="btn" id="undo-btn"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" id="redo-btn"><i class="fa fa-redo"></i></a>
</div>

const editor = grapesjs.init({
  // Indicate where to init the editor. You can also pass an HTMLElement
  container: '#gjs',
  // Get the content for the canvas directly from the element
  // As an alternative we could use: `components: '<h1>Hello World Component!</h1>'`,
  fromElement: true,
  // Size of the editor
  height: '300px',
  width: 'auto',
  // Disable the storage manager for the moment
  storageManager: false,
  // Avoid any default panel
  panels: { defaults: [...] },
  // ...
});

$('#undo-btn').click(function() {
    // undo action here
})
$('#redo-btn').click(function() {
    // redo action here
})


You can use the following code:
$('#undo-btn').click(function() {
    editor.Commands.run('core:undo');
})
$('#redo-btn').click(function() {
    editor.Commands.run('core:redo');
})

